# nice-select plugin is selecting only the first element in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, html-table

I have this select element in a table I am trying I am trying to style with the [nice-select plugin](https://bluzky.github.io/nice-select2/).

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='./assets/libraries/nice-select/css/nice-select2.css' />
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>S/N</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Fred</td>
      <td>Freeman</td>
      <td>
        <select name="gender">
          <option value="female">Female</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Barner</td>
      <td>
        <select name="gender">
          <option value="female">Female</option>
          <option value="male">Male</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src='./assets/libraries/nice-select/js/nice-select2.js'></script>
  <script src='./assets/js/app.js'></script>

  <script>
    NiceSelect.bind(document.querySelector("select")); // This styles only the first select element
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the CSS link at the top and the JS script at the bottom as the [docs](https://bluzky.github.io/nice-select2/) suggested, but only the first select is being styled, the second one is just like the normal select with no style.

I tried selecting more specific

```
<script>
    NiceSelect.bind(document.querySelector("table td select"));
</script>
```

That did not work

I also tried looping through each table row like this

```
<script>
    const tableRows = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr'));
    tableRows.forEach((row) => {
      NiceSelect.bind(row.querySelector('select'));
    });
</script>
```

But this gave an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
    at d (nice-select2.js:1:1008)
    at new p (nice-select2.js:1:1377)
    at Module.u (nice-select2.js:1:1575)
    at (index):206:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at (index):205:49
```

Comment: Or is there any other plugin anyone suggests I use?

Comment: `document.querySelector()` only ever selects the first matching element. It's hard to know what's going on in your second attempt, since `nice-select2.js` is not included.

Comment: I resolved to use jQuery even if I initially did not want to. It works with jQuery, but still, if I could get an answer in pure vanillajs, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your querySelector is incorrect, you need to replace the line below:

```
NiceSelect.bind(document.querySelector("table td select"));
```

with this line

```
NiceSelect.bind(document.querySelectorAll("table select")[0]);
```

The above line should bind `NiceSelect` to the first select element now.

If you are trying to bind `NiceSelect` to all the select elements, you can try the code snippet below. Not sure why it works but it just works for me

```
let el = document.querySelectorAll('select');
for (let i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {         
  NiceSelect.bind(document.querySelectorAll("select")[i]);
}
```